# Magento Unable to retrieve value from core session after product add to cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have added an observer to the following event

**checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

```
public function onProductAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if($product == null)
        return;
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCOLastProductAdd($product);
}
```

While on the magento cart page, I have added a custom template which is trying to read the last added product, but returns a **null**.

```
$product = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCOLastProductAdd()
```

I even tried the above routine with

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'))->setCOLastProductAdd($product);
```

I do not understand where exactly this session value is getting dropped off.

The default Magento Add to Cart follows the following route:

Product Page -> Add To Cart (goes to URL checkout/cart/add) --> Cart Page (Redirected to checkout/cart from checkout/cart/add)

I am aware that we can get the last product id from checkout/session, but I also need to track product remove from cart which can only be tracked through the event-observers.

Any pointers?

Comment: Just to add, I have confirmed the particular routine onProductAddToCart is definitely being called. (checked through debug)

Comment: Just in case if this helps to anyone, I guess I figured out the problem. The problem is because $product cannot be serialized (tried to do a serialize on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product which said unable to serialize due to some unserializable content), so I created a custom routine to save only the elements of the $product that I needed. Magento internally uses the $_SESSION to save, which saves only serializable content.